# can we execute different queries in a stored procedure same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In my stored procedure there are 8 queries for 8 tables.Each query has joins and sub queries. I am passing parameters & stored procedure name from

front end(designed in asp.net 3.5)

can we execute that 8 queries at the same time i.e. parallel execution so that I can minimize stored procedure execution time?

Regards,

N.SRIRAM

Answer (score 5):

The stored procedure runs each each query within it sequentially. If you want to run more than one at once, you'll have to create threads in your asp.net application and run each query in it's own thread. However, due to locking and processor constraints, this may not necessarily run faster.

Comment: +1: Just to add that submitting queries are queued -- doesn't matter if submitted by separate threads, one query/sp/etc will be executed before the other.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Thanks. I'm not entirely sure (haven't tested it myself) but isn't it somewhat dependent on the [isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)?

Comment: Isolation level allows for seeing dirty data, or jump queue order, but everything is still sequential.  The proof is in the transactions logs.

Comment: @OMG Ponies. Can you clarify this "doesn't matter if submitted by separate threads, one query/sp/etc will be executed before the other." This statement seems to indicate that every query is processed in order of request. (e.g. the second one won't begin until the first one is complete). Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Yes.  Separate threads in the application, but the database queues the requests regardless.